# DNODE as a way to make Java call NodeJS functions?

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, dnode

On the dnode github page (https://github.com/substack/dnode) there is a subsection that says:

```
dnode in other languages
These libraries implement the dnode protocol too so you can make RPC calls between scripts written in different languages.
```

And one of the libraies is dnode-java. Has anyone ever used this library? Is it possible to call code/functions in NodeJS from Java using Dnode? It seems I cannot find enough documentation, examples or tutorials on this, so any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "make Java and Node.js talk"? There are a thounsand ways to do that. You could do it via socket, a shared resource like file or a database, via REST services, or other types of web services, via remote procedure calls, etc, etc, etc. Now if you mean if you can use Java code in Node.js that's a different story. So, You will need to elaborate. Chances are that your question get's closed before that, though.

Comment: By communication I mean Java calling functions on the NodeJS side. I modified the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RPC means Remote procedure call,it is a protocol that allow a program to make a subroutine call on a remote machine.

Dnode is an RPC implementation, you can create a server in nodejs and a client in java and call the functions in your nodejs server.

I never tryed dnode, can't give you my option about it, but if you just want to "integrate" java and nodejs in the same machine there another options that may be more interesting, like [nodyn](https://github.com/nodyn/nodyn)